# Wrong order of output while using map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have written a program in which certain entries are made into a map. Later, using an iterator, I wanted to see the key-value pairs in this format

> key=value.

But the output is coming as

> =key value.

Here's the code

```
int main() {

    map<string,string> mp; 

    int n;
    string name, number;

    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        getline(cin,name);
        getline(cin,number);
        mp.insert(pair<string,string>(name,number));
    }

    string line;
    map<string,string>::iterator fndr;

    fndr = mp.begin();
    cout << (*fndr).first << "=" << (*fndr).second;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the input

```
2
abhay 239487
hello 23478
```

Here's the output

```
=abhay 239487
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking for people to debug your code for you? Why not start by checking the inputs to the map?

Comment: By the time you've posted your question on SO, you could have solved the problem already if you used a *debugger* and checked what is actually being put in your map etc.

Comment: @rustyx But why do that when you can get someone to write the code for you for free :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.first` is empty and the whole thing is going in `.second`. `getline()` is taking the whole string input and storing it in `number` variable. Quick solution (but won't work for names that contain spaces):

```
cin >> name;
cin >> number;
```

#### Explanation:

Before using `getline()`, you have used `cin >> n` to input the number of strings. After the input, when you press `Enter` a `\n` is appended at the end of your input. So your input actually looks like this:

```
2\n
abhay 239487\n
hello 23478\n
```

Now `cin >> n` uses `2` in the first line to store it in `n` variable but the `\n` is still there in the stream. When `getline()` is used for the next input, it finds the `\n` in the input stream and terminates thus storing **nothing** in `name` variable (`\n` is a delimiter for `getline()`). The next `getline()` finds the string `abhay 239487` before it encounters another `\n` and terminates.

Thus, we need to ignore the `\n` after `2` before the first execution of `getline()`). We can use `cin.ignore()` between the last `cin` and the first `getline()`. This will ignore the next character in the input stream.

#### Code

```
int main() {
    map<string,string> mp; 
    int n;
    string name, number;

    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        getline(cin,name);
        getline(cin,number);
        mp.insert(pair<string,string>(name,number));
    }

    string line;
    map<string,string>::iterator fndr;

    fndr = mp.begin();
    cout << (*fndr).first << "=" << (*fndr).second;

    return 0;
}
```

You can notice after using `cin.ignore()`, `abhay 239487` goes in `name` and `hello 23478` goes in `number`. The output is:

```
abhay 239487=hello 23478
```

which is expected for this case.

How to workaround the problem of segregating key: value pair ? There are two ways:

- Either you can input the `name` (key) and the corresponding `number` (value) in two different lines (This method will work for strings which contains spaces in name) like this:

  ```
  2
  abhay nayar
  239487
  hello
  23478
  ```
- Or, you can use `cin >> name >> number` to get those values (but you cannot use names that contain spaces because any whitespace character is a delimiter for `cin`).

Comment: @taskinoor Then, OP will have to take string and numbers as input in different lines.

Comment: Yes, please explain that in the answer. Otherwise it won't be off much help to OP.

Comment: Also you should explain why first becomes empty.

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway. Look at the input format.